# Providing a feedback when running db queries

Tags: php, mysql, oracle

I am currently working on some CRUD application.

Because of reasons out of my power, i have to use a system with two Databases : An oracle one, the "main" one kinda,  used by the whole company, very heavy with thousands of tables and a limited access to it (i can't change anything on it!) and a "local" one, made especially for my app, used only by its future users (not *exactly* sure, but about 20~ people i think ?).

The current way to use the app is; the server fetches every night a copy of the data it uses from the "main" db and inserts it into the "local" db. Exactly, i'm fetching a table with 36 columns and inserting it into my "local" db, where i've replicating the way the data is stored (i  mean, the 36 columns with the same data types are there too).

I was asked to add a button so that the users could manually start an import from the main db, and even if it works, i think it's an awful user experience and i want to solve the matter.

My query for the oracle server extracts (right now) 36 rows in 0.157 seconds :

```
select A.ID , ... (36 columns trust me)
            from TABLE_NAME A
            where (A.TYPEAFFAIRE = 1 and A.STATUT = 0)
            order by to_number(DECODE(REGEXP_REPLACE(A.REFERENCE, '([[:digit:]]+)', ''), '', A.REFERENCE, null))
```

This query was given to me, but i think the chokepoints are rather on Mysql (the server it's hosted on is a regular desktop machine).

```
//Fetch from oracle
            $sql = "
select A.ID , ... (36 columns trust me)
            from TABLE_NAME A
            where (A.TYPEAFFAIRE = 1 and A.STATUT = 0)
            order by to_number(DECODE(REGEXP_REPLACE(A.REFERENCE, '([[:digit:]]+)', ''), '', A.REFERENCE, null))";

           //prepare the statement and runs it
            $requete = oci_parse($connexion, $sql);
            $result = oci_execute($requete); 



            $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT IGNORE INTO vrp_affaire (`ID`, [my 36 cols]) 
                    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
```

This steps are very very long. Like, maybe 15 minutes or something. I won't add it for simplicity's sake, but there is an other query looping over this to fetch the attached files for each row returned (so again, if there's a lot of heavy files it's very very long).

I also have concerns about multiple users starting an import at the same time; should i create some sort of locking mechanism ? And what about my user getting fed up and closing the page, will interrupt the import ? Will mysql do any additional step, or even rollback(); or something ?

In definitive, i want to improve the user experience; how could i keep track of this process for them in some way ? or maybe accelerate it if there's some obvious way ? (without forgetting that my hands are kinda tied, as i don't have control other everything involved in this).

Thank you.

EDIT : This wasn't too much of a great question, but to the main problem : yeah it's slow, but only once since the future imports ignore the rows already in the base

Comment: "I also have concerns about multiple users starting an import at the same time"...would they be importing the exact same data? If so then yes you should definitely lock it down (even if you manage to improve the performance as per the very sensible suggestion from Littlefoot, below).

Comment: If the app ever grows and fetches "lots" of rows, you'll want to tune [oci_set_prefetch()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.oci-set-prefetch.php).

Answer (score 2):

From my point of view, this is wrong:

> My query for the oracle server extracts (right now) 36 rows in 0.157 seconds :

That query - as it fetches data from Oracle and inserts into MySQL, is something like

```
insert into your_table
select 36 columns
from oracle_table
where condition
-- this, below, is wrong!
order by to_number(DECODE(REGEXP_REPLACE(A.REFERENCE, '([[:digit:]]+)', ''), '', A.REFERENCE, null))
```

Remove `ORDER BY` clause, entirely. If it were some simple sorting ... bah, leave it, but - for lot of data, knowing that regular expressions are slow, that doesn't look right.

It doesn't help anything, but slows things down. Why would you care in which order rows are inserted into a table? Sort them later, in MySQL, if you have to, for presentation purposes. But, for inserting ... no benefit but much pain.

Comment: of course; i'll do that. I just didn't questioned it too much since oracle wasn't the choke point